# Cannot assign string to __type__ (type __type__ ) in multiple assignment

Tags: go, redis

I'm working on retrieving a key-value from Redis when a JSON request is given.

```
func Function (w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request) {

    request.Token = "12345"
    type Session struct {
        Token string
    ...
    }

    var session Session
    session, err2 := redisclient.Get(ctx,request.Token).Result()
    if (err2 != nil) {
        panic(err2)
    } else {
        return
    }
}
```

returns the error `cannot assign string to session (type Session) in multiple assignment` and `undefined: err2`

the redis Get() worked for another section with the identical syntax and I'm not sure why.

edit: err2 was defined by changing `=` to `:=`

Comment: `undefined: err2` seems pretty clear. You must always define all variables.

Comment: Put `var err2 error` after `var session Session`

Comment: @JimB Oh yeah, the err2 issue was cleared by changing : to :=

Comment: Variables are only created with `:=` assignment or `var` statements.  You try to assign to an `err2` that was never created first.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco fixed that. Do you know how to work with the multiple assignment error?

Comment: @JimB no I wanted Get to be returned to the Session struct

Comment: `Result()` returns a `string` (and an `error`). You cannot assign a `string` to an arbitrary struct. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @JimB Sorry I worked it out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I missed out adding that I've `json.Marshal()`-ed the struct before setting the value.

Referring to code sample in https://golangbyexample.com/golang-redis-client-example/ ,

```
//GetKey get key
func (client *redisClient) getKey(key string, src interface{}) error {
    val, err := client.c.Get(key).Result()
    if err == redis.Nil || err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(val), &src)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Previously, I `Set()` the value in Redis by using `json.Marshal()` on the struct and then setting it. So, I need to assign the `Get()` to a new variable and Unmarshal it back to the struct I created.

Solution was

```
func Function (w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request) {
request.Token = "12345"
type Session struct {
    Token string
...
}

// var session Session // this doesn't work
session, err2 := redisclient.Get(ctx,request.Token).Result() //temp var
var unmarshalsession Session // new var as struct
err3 := json.Unmarshal([]byte(session),&unmarshalsession)
if (err2 != nil || err3 != nil) {
    panic(err2)
} else {
    return
}
```

}